# Deployment to production with azure webapp deploy fails by adding python package with large dependency

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

Removing the package and deploying it to production succeeds, but adding it back, first of all, takes long and fails.

I wondered if it perhaps was the zip file that exceeded the file size limit, but the file size is only 196.4 KiB

I tried changing the deploy pipe for bitbucket from [microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.4](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy/src/master/) to [atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.1.1](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy/src/master/) but this does not work.

Current `requirements.txt`:

```
blinker==1.6.3
certifi==2023.7.22
click==8.1.7
Flask==2.3.3
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
nltk==3.8.1
pytest==7.4.3
spacy==3.7.2
Werkzeug==2.3.7
zipp==3.17.0
flask-restx==1.2.0
coverage==7.3.2
pre-commit==3.5.0
dateparser==1.1.8
deepparse==0.9.9 # package where the issue happens (don't think package is the problem)
```

Current `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` prod deploy step:

```
        name: "Deploy to Production"
        deployment: production
        trigger: manual
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.1.1
            variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
              AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
              AZURE_APP_NAME: $AZURE_APP_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: '$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip'
              DEBUG: 'true'
```

The zip is created in another step, which is stated here:

```
        image: python:3.9
        name: Build app
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install --upgrade pip
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install zip
          - zip -r $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip .
        artifacts:
          - *.zip
```

Full error trace of microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.4:

```
ERROR: Extra data: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 386, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 379, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 356, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 171, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 441, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 271, in enable_zip_deploy
    response = _check_zip_deployment_status(deployment_status_url, authorization, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 2054, in _check_zip_deployment_status
    res_dict = response.json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

My theory (I can't really find anything online) is that Azure CLI expects a response but fails since the deployment is still happening.
(Looking at this line in the trace):

> packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 2054, in _check_zip_deployment_status
> res_dict = response.json()

atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.1.1 keeps retrying, but eventually, it gets stuck and fails the pipeline. Usually this error message:

> 'status': 3, 'status_text': 'Deployment has been stopped due to SCM container restart. The restart can happen due to a management operation on site. Do not perform a management operation and a deployment operation in quick succession. Adding a small delay can help avoid any conflicts.

Online I found some answers by adding `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` and limiting it to 1800, to the Azure app settings. I am not sure if this will work and I can't try since I don't have permission to do that. But if someone made this work, please do tell me so I can look into this more

Downloading `deepparse` takes 30 minutes locally. So could it be that this taking so long fails the deployment?

Coming back to my question, did someone experience deployment with a large package and how did you solve it? Or know a better workaround to resolve this issue?

I tried the following:

- Add/remove package
- Update pipe version of azure-web-app-deploy
- Updating pip
- Create a separate environment with poetry, install the packages, and export the packages + hashes  to requirements.txt and deploy with those
- Deploy a good build, wait 3 minutes and deploy with the "broken" changes

UPDATE:
I fixed the deployment issue by adding a separate line `pip install deepparse` and removed the packge from requirements.txt

```
        image: python:3.9
        name: Build app
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install --upgrade pip
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pip install deepparse
          - apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install zip
          - zip -r $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip .
        artifacts:
          - *.zip
```

This fixed the deployment problem, however the app is now failing with a ModuleNotFoundError. This is probably due to Azure looking at requirements.txt for packages

Comment: Check if you have set up any network restrictions on your web app service. Someone in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/17000) had faced a similar problem due to that. Also you say that some package "_takes 30 minutes_" to download? Yeah then you should definitely set `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` to a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

While `deepparse` seems a light package, it has a transitive dependency on `torch`, which is huge and has an even bigger transitive dependency tree with lots of packages with C-extensions.

In an optimistic scenario pip has to download about 3GB of wheels which will lead to +5GB of modules in the python installation.

But depending on the platform the install is being run, missing wheels for your platform tags (check the output of `pip debug --verbose`) would force pip to try to compile source distributions for all that bloated torch dependency tree.

And if compiling or installing anything failed, then pip would start over again with the next package version candidate while trying to make everything match the requirements found so far.

Which, given your very restricted versions from requirements.txt may be really hard. Being that picky with your direct dependencies is a very bad idea ever since pip features a modern dependency resolver https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/

Even though the installation eventually succeeded, the modules installed in your pipeline may be incompatible with the platform tags where they are being deployed in Azure, so double check that!

Also, the zip artifact should be about 5GB. Otherwise I suspect you are missing something from the torch dependency subtree.

So, my next steps in your case would be:

1. Loosen the direct requirements version constraints
2. Introduce an advanced package manager such as `pipenv` or `pip-tools` that can resolve the whole dependency tree beforehand in a lockfile. Later, pip will install exactly that with no dependency resolving phase! If you are lacking a pre-built compatible wheel and the building toolchain for any dependency, you'll be told so and you will be able to fix that.
3. Check that the platform building the deployment artifact is compatible with the platform running such artifact.

This might look like a lot of work but it's truly an industry standard, you will live happier after this.

The JSONDecodeError feels like Azure CLI not properly handling an error in their own API, which failed to return a valid JSON document in that endpoint. Possibly because of your artifact being corrupt, but the CLI-API misunderstanding is their issue AFAIU.